# JavaScript functions fire in codepen but not JSFiddle. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run a basic JavaScript function from an external file but I'm getting inconsistent results. Basically, I can't get a button's "onclick" event to fire when I put the script in an external JS page. I can get it work in CodePen:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ThatsIsJustCrazy/pen/ezzLyK)

```
nonsense code
```

but NOT in JSFiddle:

[JS Fiddle Examlple](https://jsfiddle.net/m7ca8sns/)

I can always get it work when the script is part of the HTML page but I don't want to do that. Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

jsfiddle puts the javascript code in its own context:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
    function clickFunction()
    {
      alert("this is working");
    }
}//]]>
```

But codepen puts the js in the global scope.